# How to plot figures with different angles in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to plot a curve for different angles

```
v=10; 
teta=20; % angle of the projectile motion
vx=v*cos(teta); % velocity in x axis
vy=v*sin(teta); % velocity in y axis
x=0:20;
y=zeros(size(x));

y=vy.*(x./vx)-(0.5*9.81*(x./vx).^2); % here I calculate the height of the ball in y axis
plot(x,y)
set(gca,'ylim',[0,5])
```

How can I change theta in each time to plot theta for 20 and 40 and 60 degrees in same plot ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways of achieving what you need. I have written down one of them below:

- Create an array of all the desired values for theta
- generate vx and vy for each theta. NOTE: You have used theta in degrees, however sin and cos functions take input in radians so you need to do the conversion beforehand.
- In a for loop generate the value of y for each theta value.
- Plot the outcomes.

The code is as below:

```
v=10; 
teta=[20 40 60]; % angle of the projectile motion
vx=v*cos(pi*teta/180); % velocity in x axis
vy=v*sin(pi*teta/180); % velocity in y axis
x=0:20;
y=zeros(size(x));
for i=1:length(vx)
    y(i,:)=vy(i).*(x./vx(i))-(0.5*9.81*(x./vx(i)).^2); % here I calculate the height of the ball in y axis
end
plot(x,y)
set(gca,'ylim',[0,5])
```

This generates a plot as shown below:
[matlab plot for 3 theta values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N77Og.png)

That is a very basic solution for you to get going.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks why you divide theta by 180 in `vx=v*cos(pi*teta/180);` do you mean that the value must be in radians and not in grades

Comment: Yes. That is just a simple way to convert angle from degrees to radians. So you can input the angle in degrees and this will be converted to radians for cos and sine.

Comment: Alternatively you can use cosd which is cosine in degrees. cosd - http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cosd.html, cos - http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cos.html